# What happen if an npm package installation canceled?

Tags: npm

What happen if the **npm** package installation canceled with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>? Is the package partially downloaded or download will revert?

Comment: download will revert

Comment: Thanks for quick response and editing.